# Adding border around an UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using below code to add text and border to selected image from cameraroll.

```
-(UIImage*)image:(UIImage*)image withText:(NSString*)text atPoint:(CGPoint)point{
if (text) {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0);
    [image drawInRect:rect];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName           : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:80],
                                 //NSStrokeWidthAttributeName    : @(4),
                                 NSStrokeColorAttributeName    : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    [text drawAtPoint:point withAttributes:attributes];

    CALayer *l = [self.imageView layer];
    [l setBorderWidth:10.0];
    [l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
}
return newImage;
}
```

When i click on save button in my app, i am saving edited image to cameraroll.But edited image inside cameraroll only has text without any added border. Whether i am missing anything in above code to add and save border around image? Is there any other way to add border other than CALayer?

Comment: You are adding border to imageView's layer while should be drawing in image context.

Comment: @Keenle i didn't get you. Can you make me understand with code?

Comment: A `UIImage` is a structure containing, eventually, bits and bytes. You can send an image to a peed, store it to disk, or display it on the screen. A `CALayer` is a *Core Animation Layer*, pretty much related to a `UIView`, specifically for display. In short, changing properties of the display layer has no permanent effect on your image. @Keenle code actually draws inside your image, effectively modifying it.

Comment: As per question: `Whether i am missing anything in above code to add and save border around image?` I am modifying image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
CALayer *l = [self.imageView layer];
[l setBorderWidth:10.0];
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]];
```

With this:

```
UIBezierPath *rectangleBezier = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];
rectangleBezier.lineWidth = 20.0f; // 10 * 2 because line drawn from the center of edge
[[UIColor blueColor] setStroke];
[rectangleBezier stroke];
```

**Remarks:**
`CALayer *l = [self.imageView layer];` has nothing to do with UIImage data. imageView's layer change imageView presentation. Not the content of UIImage.

Answer (score 0):

I will respond to "Adding a border around an UIImage **in a UIView**"

From far, the easiest method is to insert another view in the view hierarchy.

```
[self.view insertSubview:({
    UIView * border = [[UIView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.imageView.frame, -1, -1)];
    border.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    border;
})
belowSubview:self.imageView];
```